# How to cut a phrase in half in python

Tags: python, split

I have a phrase that needs to be cut in half (only first half will be used). I would only like to use the half of the line. Here is my code,

```
 def license_trial_card(self):
    card = self.driver.find_element(*Elements._License_card_text)
    cardtext = card.text
    split = cardtext.split(' ', 4)
    return split
```

The output I am getting is,

```
['Your', 'Trial', 'is', 'valid', 'until 24/08/2017 14:06.']
```

I only need to use the part 'Your Trial is valid until'. The rest of the phrase will not be used for verification as the date/time will be different every time.

Can anyone help?

Comment: so you have a list, and you want all but the last entry? `split[:-1]`

Comment: if you need to keep the word 'until', just change the 4 to a 5

Comment: Does this first part of the text ever change? If not, consider making it a class attribute, or property. There's no reason to repopulate that text every time it is fetched.

Comment: @RickTeachey Will you please elaborate? I am confused. The other answer worked btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the var without the last element, and change 4 for 5 to get the "until" as well:

```
 def license_trial_card(self):
    card = self.driver.find_element(*Elements._License_card_text)
    cardtext = card.text
    split = cardtext.split(' ', 5)
    joined = ' '.join(split[:-1])
    return joined
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it's a phrase that will be reused a lot without changing. I suggest entering the text as a class property with a format specification at the end. The format specification could be populated by a stored date string.

One way to do all of that (and to make sure you don't accidentally overwrite the text) would be:

```
class Mine(): 
    _validuntil = 'Your Trial is valid until {}'
    def __init__(self):
        self._valid_date = get_the_cuttoff_date_text()
    @property
    def validuntil(self):
        return self._validuntil.format(self.valid_date)
    @property
    def valid_date(self):
        return self._valid_date
```

Assuming your `get_the_cuttoff_date_text()` function (during the object initialization phase) provides the correct string, now you can just do:

```
print(my_object.validuntil)
```

Comment: Thanks, Rick. Date and time are not needed for validation for my test case. The trial is for 3 months and it is covered in another test case.

Comment: That's even easier. Updated.